# Allow users to post their videos to my wordpress website?

Tags: posts, uploads, users, videos

I want to allow users to post their suggested videos on my website through url and file upload options. i went through the `user submitted forms` plugin but in that there is only option for image upload .

Once posted i want that videos to be on my website page ?

Any help is appreciated ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to develop own code for it? If you need plugin, then maybe this will work for you: "Frontend Uploader" https://wordpress.org/plugins/frontend-uploader/

Comment: Thanks @RameshPardhi. With this can i upload videos and their hyperlinks too ?

Comment: These file can be upload using this plugin. Try and explore it.
Comma Separated Values File (.csv),
 MP3 Audio File (.mp3),
 Audio Video Interleave File (.avi),
 MIDI File (.mid),
 WAVE Audio File (.wav),
 Windows Media Audio File (.wma),

Comment: Hi.  Welcome to WPSE.  You can find out the sorts of question we answer at [help/on-topic] Specifically plugin recommendations are off-topic.  You can ask for help with your own code and are expected to show what you've tried to achieve for yourself so far.